# I Implemented the delete Feature in OpenLayers 4 but cannot delete the corresponding Popup

Tags: openlayers

I have tried implementing the measure feature from an OpenLayers example and implemented a delete feature button. It works well but I was unable make it delete the corresponding measure popup with it. I am a JavaScript beginner.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Measure</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css" />
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script
        src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
    <style>
        .tooltip {
            position: relative;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            border-radius: 4px;
            color: white;
            padding: 4px 8px;
            opacity: 0.7;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        .tooltip-measure {
            opacity: 1;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .tooltip-static {
            background-color: #ffcc33;
            color: black;
            border: 1px solid white;
        }

        .tooltip-measure:before,
        .tooltip-static:before {
            border-top: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            border-right: 6px solid transparent;
            border-left: 6px solid transparent;
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -6px;
            margin-left: -7px;
            left: 50%;
        }

        .tooltip-static:before {
            border-top-color: #ffcc33;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <form class="form-inline">
        <label>Measurement type &nbsp;</label>
        <select id="type">
            <option value="length">Length (LineString)</option>
            <option value="area">Area (Polygon)</option>
        </select>
        <button id="delete-button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
            Delete
        </button>

        <div id="js-overlay">
            <button id="js-remove">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p>jhghjgjh jg jh</p>
    <script>
        var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM(),
        });

        var source = new ol.source.Vector();

        var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: source,
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)",
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: "#ffcc33",
                    width: 2,
                }),
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 7,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: "#ffcc33",
                    }),
                }),
            }),
        });

        /**
         * Currently drawn feature.
         * @type {ol.Feature}
         */
        var sketch;

        /**
         * The help tooltip element.
         * @type {Element}
         */
        var helpTooltipElement;

        /**
         * Overlay to show the help messages.
         * @type {ol.Overlay}
         */
        var helpTooltip;

        /**
         * The measure tooltip element.
         * @type {Element}
         */
        var measureTooltipElement;

        /**
         * Overlay to show the measurement.
         * @type {ol.Overlay}
         */
        var measureTooltip;

        /**
         * Message to show when the user is drawing a polygon.
         * @type {string}
         */
        var continuePolygonMsg = "Click to continue drawing the polygon";

        /**
         * Message to show when the user is drawing a line.
         * @type {string}
         */
        var continueLineMsg = "Click to continue drawing the line";

        /**
         * Handle pointer move.
         * @param {ol.MapBrowserEvent} evt The event.
         */
        var pointerMoveHandler = function (evt) {
            if (evt.dragging) {
                return;
            }
            /** @type {string} */
            var helpMsg = "Click to start drawing";

            if (sketch) {
                var geom = sketch.getGeometry();
                if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
                    helpMsg = continuePolygonMsg;
                } else if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {
                    helpMsg = continueLineMsg;
                }
            }

            helpTooltipElement.innerHTML = helpMsg;
            helpTooltip.setPosition(evt.coordinate);

            helpTooltipElement.classList.remove("hidden");
        };

        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [raster, vector],
            target: "map",
            view: new ol.View({
                center: [-11000000, 4600000],
                zoom: 15,
            }),
        });

        map.on("pointermove", pointerMoveHandler);

        map.getViewport().addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
            helpTooltipElement.classList.add("hidden");
        });

        var typeSelect = document.getElementById("type");

        var draw; // global so we can remove it later

        /**
         * Format length output.
         * @param {ol.geom.LineString} line The line.
         * @return {string} The formatted length.
         */
        var formatLength = function (line) {
            var length = ol.Sphere.getLength(line);
            var output;
            if (length > 100) {
                output =
                    Math.round((length / 1000) * 100) / 100 + " " + "km";
            } else {
                output = Math.round(length * 100) / 100 + " " + "m";
            }
            return output;
        };

        /**
         * Format area output.
         * @param {ol.geom.Polygon} polygon The polygon.
         * @return {string} Formatted area.
         */
        var formatArea = function (polygon) {
            var area = ol.Sphere.getArea(polygon);
            var output;
            if (area > 10000) {
                output =
                    Math.round((area / 1000000) * 100) / 100 +
                    " " +
                    "km<sup>2</sup>";
            } else {
                output =
                    Math.round(area * 100) / 100 + " " + "m<sup>2</sup>";
            }
            return output;
        };

        function addInteraction() {
            var type =
                typeSelect.value == "area" ? "Polygon" : "LineString";
            draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                source: source,
                type: type,
                style: new ol.style.Style({
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)",
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
                        lineDash: [10, 10],
                        width: 2,
                    }),
                    image: new ol.style.Circle({
                        radius: 5,
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)",
                        }),
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)",
                        }),
                    }),
                }),
            });
            map.addInteraction(draw);

            createMeasureTooltip();
            createHelpTooltip();

            var listener;
            draw.on(
                "drawstart",
                function (evt) {
                    // set sketch
                    sketch = evt.feature;

                    /** @type {ol.Coordinate|undefined} */
                    var tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;

                    listener = sketch
                        .getGeometry()
                        .on("change", function (evt) {
                            var geom = evt.target;
                            var output;
                            if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
                                output = formatArea(geom);
                                tooltipCoord = geom
                                    .getInteriorPoint()
                                    .getCoordinates();
                            } else if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {
                                output = formatLength(geom);
                                tooltipCoord = geom.getLastCoordinate();
                            }
                            measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
                            measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
                        });
                },
                this
            );

            draw.on(
                "drawend",
                function () {
                    measureTooltipElement.className =
                        "tooltip tooltip-static";
                    measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
                    // unset sketch
                    sketch = null;
                    // unset tooltip so that a new one can be created
                    measureTooltipElement = null;
                    createMeasureTooltip();
                    ol.Observable.unByKey(listener);
                },
                this
            );
        }

        /**
         * Creates a new help tooltip
         */
        function createHelpTooltip() {
            if (helpTooltipElement) {
                helpTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(
                    helpTooltipElement
                );
            }
            helpTooltipElement = document.createElement("div");
            helpTooltipElement.className = "tooltip hidden";
            helpTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
                element: helpTooltipElement,
                offset: [15, 0],
                positioning: "center-left",
            });
            map.addOverlay(helpTooltip);
        }

        /**
         * Creates a new measure tooltip
         */
        function createMeasureTooltip() {
            if (measureTooltipElement) {
                measureTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(
                    measureTooltipElement
                );
            }
            measureTooltipElement = document.createElement("div");
            measureTooltipElement.className = "tooltip tooltip-measure";
            measureTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
                element: measureTooltipElement,
                offset: [0, -15],
                positioning: "bottom-center",
            });
            map.addOverlay(measureTooltip);
        }

        /**
         * Let user change the geometry type.
         */
        typeSelect.onchange = function () {
            map.removeInteraction(draw);
            addInteraction();
        };

        addInteraction();



        //IT ALL STARTS HERE
        document.getElementById("js-remove").addEventListener("click", function () {
            vector.getSource().removeFeature(selectedFeature);
            overlay.setPosition(undefined);
            interaction.getFeatures().clear();
        });
        var remove_b = document.getElementById("js-overlay");
        var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
            element: remove_b,
        });
        map.addOverlay(overlay);
        document.getElementById("js-overlay").style.display = "block";


        var selectedFeature;
        function onClick(id, callback) {
            document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("click", callback);
        }


        interaction = new ol.interaction.Select({
            condition: ol.events.condition.click,
            layers: [vector],
        });
        map.addInteraction(interaction);

        interaction.on("select", function (event) {
            selectedFeature = event.selected[0];
            selectedFeature
                ? overlay.setPosition(
                    selectedFeature.getGeometry().getExtent()
                )
                : overlay.setPosition(undefined);
        });



    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to delete measure tooltip, displayed when drawing of feature is finished, by clicking on `Delete` button?

Comment: Yes...I want to delete measure tooltip displayed when draing of feature is finished by clicking Delete button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to delete the parents of the `tooltip-static` under `js-remove` click event. However, to only delete the selected features tooltip together with the feature, you need to bind the tooltip with the feature using the feature id `feature.xp` by adding the feature.xp in the `draw.on("drawend"..)` method.

```
        draw.on(
            "drawend",
            function (evt) {
                // Attach the feature xp to the className to get the feature tooltip
                measureTooltipElement.className =
                    "tooltip tooltip-static " + evt.feature.xp;
                measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
                // unset sketch
                sketch = null;
                // unset tooltip so that a new one can be created
                measureTooltipElement = null;
                createMeasureTooltip();
                ol.Observable.unByKey(listener);
            },
            this
        );
```

Then remove only the selected and being removed feature's tooltip using the code below.

```
    document.getElementById("js-remove").addEventListener("click", function () {
        vector.getSource().removeFeature(selectedFeature);
        overlay.setPosition(undefined);
        interaction.getFeatures().clear();

        // Get the feature's measure tooltip only
        var tips = document.getElementsByClassName(selectedFeature.xp);
        //Remove the tip associated with this current feature being removed
        if (tips.length > 0){
               tips[0].parentNode.remove();
        }
    });
```

[**Check it out on JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/andex/pb1fn2gr/35/)

Comment: Thanks for this, I did implement this before, the issue comes when you have multiple drawn features. It tends to delete some and leave out some. I want deleted the selected feature and its corresponding popup without affecting others.

Comment: This finds all `tooltip-static` and delete them. So there will be no left overs. It is executed every-time the Remove button is clicked.

Comment: @BelloOluwasegunCornelius I have posted a JSFiddle so that you can test it.

Comment: Thanks again @wondim, I have checked the fiddle, and on drawing multiple features, there is a problem. Can you try this out....thanks again.

Comment: @BelloOluwasegunCornelius You are welcome. I see the problem. So do you want to remove the tooltip for the removed feature only?

Comment: Yes i want to remove the tooltip for the removed feature only...thanks

Comment: @BelloOluwasegunCornelius I have updated my answer and the JSFiddle. It is working as expected.

Comment: Seems to work, and i am trying to trace what you changed, can you please comment the areas you changed, this will help a lot as i am a javascript beginner. thanks again.

Comment: @BelloOluwasegunCornelius great! I have already commented on the areas where I made the changes. Also I explained them on the answer. Feel free to ask any questions that is not clear on the comment section.

Comment: @BelloOluwasegunCornelius I have added a comment that says `Changed here` in the code blocks I made changes in the updated JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Your explanation really helped and i was able to also implement it with Openlayer6 using evt.feature.ol_uid.

Comment: @BelloOluwasegunCornelius you are most welcome. I am glad it helped.